# Как написать проверку по ключу в словаре, который находится в списке?

Tags: python

Имею данный код:

```
releases = []
for release in all_release_dates:
    if release['iso_3166_1']:
       releases.append(release['release_dates'])
```

В словарь передаются следующие значения, вот его малая часть:

```
[[{'certification': 'G', 'iso_639_1': '', 'note': 'Washington, D.C.', 'release_date': '1968-04-02T00:00:00.000Z', 'type': 1}], 
 [{'certification': '', 'iso_639_1': None, 'note': "Kyiv Critics' Week", 'release_date': '2020-10-28T00:00:00.000Z', 'type': 2}], 
 [{'certification': '11', 'iso_639_1': 'en', 'note': '', 'release_date': '1968-08-27T00:00:00.000Z', 'type': 3}], ]
```

И, собственно, сам вопрос: как сделать проверку по каждому словарю по ключу `'type'`? И если он равен `1`, то выводилось бы значение из того же словаря по ключу `'release_date'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итерируете исходный список, внутри него у Вас еще один список, уже внутри которого словарь.

Сначала проверяет вхождение ключа `type` и его равенство `1` через `if dict.get('type') == 1`, если оно существует, то через `dict.get('release_date')` пытаетесь получить результат. Если такого ключа не будет, то получите `None`

```
data = [[{'certification': 'G', 'iso_639_1': '', 'note': 'Washington, D.C.', 'release_date': '1968-04-02T00:00:00.000Z', 'type': 1}],
 [{'certification': '', 'iso_639_1': None, 'note': "Kyiv Critics' Week", 'release_date': '2020-10-28T00:00:00.000Z', 'type': 2}],
 [{'certification': '11', 'iso_639_1': 'en', 'note': '', 'release_date': '1968-08-27T00:00:00.000Z', 'type': 3}], ]

for d in data:
    if d[0].get('type') == 1:
        print(d[0].get('release_date'))
```